# Objective-C using delegate methods for multiple services

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, delegates

I have a problem using delegates. I have an object that provides some services. Now these services need another (async) service (another object provides that). So two different services require the same (third) service. These two calls need to be handled different in the delegate method of the third service. How do i do that? Is there a design pattern for that?

I would just create some ServiceHandlerObject and register that as the third services delegate. And then just use a different ServiceHandlerObject for each service to provide. But i have no idea if this is "the way you do it".

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Are you looking for a way to specify more than one delegate for each service? i.e. to multicast delegates?

Comment: The method i call looks like -(void)loadContentOfPath:(NSString *)path;
Now when the method is done loading the content, the delegate gets called with something like this: -(void)didLoadContent:(NSArray *)content ofPath:(NSString *)path;
I call the method with multiple purposes so the received data in the delegate method needs to be handled different. How do i do this? I hope its understandable now.

Comment: i am not sure what you are upto. Smells me like multithreading,pls be clear with your question...

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking but perhaps if `loadContentsOfPath` completes with different 'purposes' you could use `NSNotificationCenter` to send different notifications for each 'purpose' then the other classes could subscribe to the notifications they were interested in.